# How to boot from ssd

Tags: uefi, ssd, bios

I am fairly new to Linux, and I've just installed Ubuntu. The PC booted from my HDD but when I try to find the SSD in a terminal emulation window, I can't find it, and I want to boot from the SSD.

I have tried to research online and I found out it might be running on RAID instead of AHCI, so I opened the BIOS and couldn't find the SSD settings there either. I am certain the SSD is connected to the PC because it worked perfectly fine when Windows was installed and running.

Comment: Yes this question is confusing. If needed i would gladly explain further. :3. Also, sorry for the grammar. English is not my first language.

Comment: May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Please add your Ubuntu version and the results of `ls /dev/sd* /dev/nvme*` to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have been given an option on which drive to install your boot folder with the installer. You may be able to use `dd` tool to clone your boot folder and move it on to your ssd. Where are you expecting your ssd to show up? Generally linux will mount your drives under either the `/mount` folder or `/run/media/user/` folder. I can't remember whihc it is for ubuntu.

Check out the answers here for some more information on cloning/moving `/boot`
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63977/moving-boot-and-mbr-to-a-new-drive

Comment: Recommending `dd` at this early stage in finding out the facts makes me uncomfortable. Doubly so with a new user.